# HttpClient not supporting PostAsJsonAsync method & dll in C#

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to call a API in my Windows App .Net 4.6.1

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("https://smsmisr.com/");
            client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
            var sendtime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "api/webapi/?" +
            "username=XXXxx" +
            "&password=XXXXXX" +
            "&language= 3 Or 2 Or 1" +
            "&sender=Your Sender " +
            "&mobile=2012XXXXXX, 2011XXXX" +
            "&message=Encoded Message" +
            "&DelayUntil=" + sendtime
            ).Result;
```

and while writing the code I am getting the error

**Error CS1501  No overload for method 'PostAsJsonAsync' takes 1 arguments**

after searching i added this references :

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll;
```

but this error appear:
**Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'dll' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.Http.Formatting' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

Comment: The dll part is never required

Comment: i removed it  and this error still appear **Error CS1501 No overload for method 'PostAsJsonAsync' takes 1 arguments**

Comment: `using System.Net.Http.Formatting`

Comment: Why are you calling `PostAsJsonAsync` without, ummm, posting any JSON? That is not JSON - it is just querystring parameters. No JSON involved.

Comment: @BassemKamalM Can you talk us through why you want to call that method _specifically_?

Comment: @mjwills I do not have enough information about API, and the website (sms service) provide me with code to connect my project with its service. i tried to contact them to request its support but no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944682(v=vs.118)) you can see what all the overloads of that method are. You probably want to pass the uri and the payload object, something like:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/webapi", [your object instance here]);
```

Currently, you are passing a single String, hence the error.

Also, the using statement that needs correction:

```
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
```

Comment: You may as well add in the answer to the other error he is getting (he has `using System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`, but it should be `using System.Net.Http.Formatting`)

Comment: i tied that and the response msg is : {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Mon, 03 Aug 2020 08:00:39 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  Content-Length: 75
  Content-Type: text/html
}}

Comment: That means you are sending data to the server the server probably doesn't know how to interoperate and is crashing.

Answer (score -1):

Did you implemented PostAsJsonAsync method that takes one argument?

That error occurs when user did not implement a method required by inherited class

Comment: That error shows up when it's implemented -- he just isn't sending in the correct amount of parameters to said method. This answer is wrong.